# Trying to pass through a sound card to a windows 10 vm

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, sound-card, asio

I am using VMware Workstation 16. The host computer is Also Windows 10 x64 VM is Windows 10 x64. The sound card I am trying to pass through is a Focusrite 2i2 Gen2. It's important for me to get ASIO Support in the VM.

**Steps I tried:**

- Installed Official Focusrite Drivers inside the VM (It gets recognized and it thinks that it's working) [Screenshot of Focusrite settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwhkb.png)
- On DAW it takes input but no output
- I would have tried to use ASIO4ALL but it creates too much delay so it doesnt work out for me (Trying to solve it using official drivers)
- At this time i am trying to use VirtualBox as the supervisor so I will see how that goes and inform you. (I would prefer to use VMWare)

**EDIT:**

- I thought of another way to use my soundcard. Maybe if I am able to find an application that can connect my ASIO card on my host computer and send the ASIO data to the VM using network (if it's low enough latency)

If you would need me to provide more information feel free to ask.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Trying to run a DAW in a VM has never been a good idea. I'm pretty sure this will not work. ASIO needs direct access to the hardware. A VM has an interpreter between it & the hardware. I'm surprised you got input to work, tbh. If you do get it to work, expect to have to use a buffer more in the 4096 range than 48

Comment: Is this a USB sound car?

Comment: @harrymc Yes it is

Comment: After your edit - that will be slow as molasses; you're going to be going through not only the abysmal Windows audio router, but the VM's as well. What DAW are you using & have you asked them if they think this can be done? [I know ASIO is Steinberg, but idk who has licensed it these days]